# cakephp find method not returning object even if data exists

Tags: cakephp, controller

i'm new to cakephp and facing problems with AJAX requests

Here is the situtation, i'm registering a user with $.ajax  jquery method:

```
function doregistration(){

if(isValidRegistrationForm()){

    var frm = $(".frmregister").serialize();

    $("#msgregister").html("Checking...");

    $.ajax({
        url: 'createuser',
        type: 'POST',
        data: frm,
        success: function(result){
            alert(result);
            $("#msgregister").html(result);

            if(result.indexOf("registered")>-1){
                clearRegistrationForm();
            }
        }
    });     
}
}
```

i'm getting the value of username successfully in the following controller:

```
if($this->request->isAjax()){

        $username = $this->request->data['username'];

        $ar = $this->User->find("all", array('conditions' => array('User.username' => $username)));
```

The problem is $ar shows count($ar) as 1 but is not having any object
as if I try to write

```
$user = $ar[0];
```

it says no data at index 0.

Comment: Why don't you debug your return data to see what it contains?
`count()` might return 1 for other reasons: [If var is not an array or not an object with implemented Countable interface, 1 will be returned](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php#refsect1-function.count-returnvalues). You are also better running `find('first')` instead of `find('all')` in this situation.

Comment: I used foreach loop to read the objects

Comment: How about `print_r`, `var_dump` or even cake's `debug()` and `debugKit`? If your PHP array doesn't have numeric indices then array[<number>] will fail because an identifying numeric key doesn't exist but count() will tell you the number of keys and their values can be accessed by array['keyname'].